# What is a best practice to represent a boolean value in a shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I know, that there are boolean values in `bash`, but I don't ever see them used anywhere.

I want to write a wrapper for some often looked up information on my machine, for example, is this particular USB drive inserted/mounted.

What would be the best practice to achieve that?

- A string?

  ```
  drive_xyz_available=true
  ```
- A number (0 for true, ≠0 for false)?

  ```
  drive_xyz_available=0    # evaluates to true
  ```
- A function?

  ```
  drive_xyz_available() { 
      if available_magic; then 
              return 0 
      else 
              return 1 
      fi
  }
  ```

I mostly wonder about, what would be expected by other people who would want to use the wrapper. Would they expect a boolean value, a command like variable or  a function to call?

From a security standpoint I would think the second option is the safest, but I would love to hear your experiences.

Comment: `help true ; help false ; help exit`

Comment: @Costas Would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool(){ return "$((!${#1}))"; }

if bool "$var"
then : do true
else : do false
```

Just set a variable to anything but not-null for the above to work, though `[ -n "$var" ]` would be shorter, if not as obvious.

In general when a script interprets an environment variable to be either true or false, it will interpret any value at all to be true *(and sometimes use said value to configure some option)* or else a null value as false.

The above returns the boolean `!not` value of its first argument's len - if the argument contains any number of characters other than 0 it returns 0, else, if no characters at all, it returns 1. This is the same test you can perform with `[ -n "$var" ]`, basically, but it just wraps it in a little function named `bool()`.

This is typically how a *flag* variable works. For example:

```
[ -d "$dir" ] || dir=
```

Where other parts of a script need only look for any value at all in `$dir` to gauge its usefulness. This also comes in handy where parameter substitution is concerned - as parameters can be expanded to default values to fill in for empty or unset ones, but will otherwise expand to a preset value like...

```
for set in yes ''
do echo "${set:-unset or null}"
done
```

...which would print...

```
yes
unset or null
```

Of course, it is also possible to do the opposite with `:+` but that can only ever give you a preset default or nothing at all, whereas the above form can give you a value or a default value.

And so regarding the three choices - any one could work depending on how you choose to implement it. The function's return is self-testing, but, if that return needs saving for any reason, will need to be put in a variable. It depends on the use case - is the boolean value you wish to evaluate a test once and done type? If so, do the function, else either of the other two is probably necessary.

Comment: I don't think you're answering my question. I'm not asking how booleans could be used in a shell script, but what way is the most common and would be expected by another user. If my question is unclear I would be happy to edit it. Also a short explanation for what your answer does would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: @Minix Any better?

Comment: I generally assign `true` or `false` to a variable, you can then do `if $variable; then ...`

Comment: @wurtel - that relies on default `$IFS` - and if the var's value might contain user input of any kind, then also on sheer good luck. If the value is not unknown to begin with then there is little need to test it. More safely you can do `if ${var:+":"} false; then` when working w/ boolean null/not null values. But that is rarely more useful than `[ -n "$var" ] &&`

Comment: If I start my script with `variable=false` and then set it to true according to whatever condition (just like I would when using a variable in C) then there's no problem whatsoever, What's your obsession with varying IFS values and random variable values etc. anyway...

Comment: @wurtel - no obsession, it's just important to handle all cases. Unintended behavior is a bug - good code is bug free. `$IFS` is a global modifier - it affects all of the code you write, and, for POSIX shells, can be passed in via the environment. So `IFS=t wurtel.sh` would cause your test to fail in that case. Given a POSIX `sh`, that is, and an `#!/bin/sh` bangline. `bash`, for example, though, ignores `$IFS` in the environment. But a `bash` bangline only limits the usefulness of your code more than it need be because you didn't like the quotes.

Comment: If you go out of your way to set bizarre values of IFS in your environment to break things then you can also just edit the script... You could also argue that putting such values of IFS in the environment is extremely bad practice. I could also just initialize IFS in my script to something sane.

Comment: @wurtel - which is a good idea. But a user going out of their way to do bizarre things with the environment in which the code you write is executed should be your expectation in the first place - robust code handles it, buggy code doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash` every variable is essentially a string (or an array or a function, but let's talk about regular variables here).

The conditions are parsed based on the return values of the test commands -- the return value is not a variable, it's an exit state. When you evaluate `if [ ... ]` or `if [[ ]]` or `if grep something` or anything like that, the return value 0 (not string 0, but exit status 0 = success) means true and the rest mean false (so, exactly the opposite from what you are used to in compiled programming languages, but because there is one way to succeed and many ways to fail, and the expected outcome of execution is usually success, 0 is used as the most common default result if nothing goes wrong). This is very useful because any binary can be used as a test - if it fails, it's false, otherwise it's true.

`true` and `false` programs (usually overridden by builtins) are just usefull little programs that do nothing -- `true` succeeds at doing nothing, and exits with 0, while `false` tries doing nothing and "fails", exitting with 1. Sounds pointless but it's very handy for scripting.

As for how to pass truthfullness around, it's up to you. It's quite common to just use "y" or "yes" for truth and use `if [ x"$variable" = x"yes" ]` (appended the dummy string `x` because if `$variable` happens to be zero length, this protects from creating a bogus command `if [ = "yes" ]` which doesn't parse). It may also be useful to simply use an empty string for false, and use `[ -z "$variable ]` to test if it's zero-length (or `-n` for it to be nonzero).

Anyway, it's quite rare to actually need to pass around boolean values in `bash` - it's much more common to simply `exit` on failure, or return a useful result (or zero if something goes wrong, and test for empty string), and most of the cases can test for failure directly from the exit statatus.

---

In your case, you want a function that will act as any other command (therefore, return 0 on success), so your last option seems the right choice.

Also, you may not even need `return` statement. If the function is simple enough, you can use the fact that it simply returns the status of the last executed command in the function. So your function can simply be

```
drive_xyz_available() {
   [ -e /dev/disk/by-uuid/whatever ]
}
```

if you are testing for existence of a device node (or grep `/proc/mounts` to check if it's mounted?).

Comment: That's a very nice summary, thank you for taking the time to write it up. Can I infer from your last paragraph, that you would consider the option of `drive_xyz_available()` to be the most common?

Comment: Can you provide some examples for the common `y = true` case? In my experience, most wrapper scripts test for any not null value to consider it true - at least where interpreted environment variables are concerned. Otherwise they ignore shell cars altogether.

Comment: The dummy string for the `if` test is not necessary if the variable is quoted; `if [ "$variable" = "yes" ]` works fine even if $variable is not set.

Comment: *true and false programs (usually overridden by builtins) are just usefull little programs that do nothing -- true succeeds at doing nothing, and exits with 0, while false tries doing nothing and "fails", exitting with 1. Sounds pointless but it's very handy for scripting.*

When using `return`, isn’t `return 0` a tiny bit more effective than `return true`? Because the second one implies calling a program, whereas 0 is more “direct”?


Probably a silly question… and sure `return true` is far more easy to read.

Answer (score -2):

Basically any number that is not 0 is true, and 0 is false. Reason for returning values as 0 for a successfull ending of a script or any other number to identify different kind of errors.

`$?` will return the exit code of the previous command/executable, being 0 success and any other number the error that has been returned.

So I would use that method for true/false. `if (( ! $? ));then OK;else NOOK;fi`

Comment: I'll write one up for the last option, then. Thank you.

Comment: A nonzero number is false actually, and zero is true. Just look at output of `true; echo $?` and `false; echo $?`.

Comment: @Ruslan.  Did you check the output of my command? I guess you didn't, otherwise you wouldn't have stated what you did. 0 is false, any other number is true, reason to negate `!` the result for it to be TRUE. Result from a command is 0 when it has finished correctly, which doesn't mean that 0 is true. The word `true` may be 0, but 0 is never true as the `if` condition demonstrates.

Comment: That's the same as saying that in C/C++, `0` is `true` because `if(!x){True();}else{False();}` will call `True()` when `x==0`. But the correct check would be not `!x`, but rather `!!x`.

Comment: You are waaaaaaay wrong. I'm not talking about what and which order has whatever you write after the `if` I just state the fact that here (in bash, or ksh, or tsh, or....) as in C/C++ a 0 is FALSE, any other number is TRUE, as you can read in the link that follows, initial implementatins of C provided no boolean type, being defined as ints where 0 was FALSE and 1 TRUE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type.

Comment: I remember having a hard time to deal with 0 for true (actually "success"…) and 1 or another number for false when I discovered the shell language. Because when I learnt boolean at school, 1 was true, and 0 false.
And actually, this is still how it works, in *bc*, or even in the shell arithmetic evaluation : `$((4<3))`  is zero ;)